# Как нормально отобразить массив в массиве (JSON) в GraphQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

Rails, GraphQL Ruby и поле с типом JSON в таблице PostgreSQL.

В этом поле хранятся записи двух видов:

1. `["One","Two","Three"]`
2. `[["One","Two","Three"]]`

Это сделано специально. Так нужно.

Если Rails сам по себе эти данные отображает как надо, то gem GraphQL внутри себя корректно работает только с первым видом.

Второй вид он отобразит так:

```
"json_field": [
    "[\"One\", \"Two\", \"Three\"]"
]
```

За отображение отвечает этот код:

```
field :json_field, types[types.String]
```

Я понимаю почему второй вариант выглядит в выдаче именно так, но я не могу понять как это исправить.

Помогите это побороть, пожалуйста.

Comment: [`UnionType`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/graphql/1.6.6/GraphQL/UnionType) ищете что ль?

Comment: @D-side не совсем. В `UnionType` судя по всему нельзя определить массив и массив в массиве. По крайней мере у меня на это ругался: `Field Post.json_field is invalid: possible_types must contain GraphQL::ObjectType, not Array ([String])`...

Comment: Ох и упоротая же там система типов :]

Comment: @D-side согласен. Судя по всему основная проблема - это `not GraphQL::ScalarType (String)`. И я не знаю как ее обойти. Даже если бы я создал два типа, то я не понимаю как мне в них описать массив и массив в массиве...